# Required field in custom content type not required in custom list instance

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, content-type, required-field

I have an issue with a custom SharePoint 2013 solution. Among other components, it consists of:

- a feature with several custom fields with different types, some of which are taxonomy fields,
- a feature with three custom content types using different sets of the custom fields with partially different configuration, e.g. whether they are required or not,
- a feature with a custom document library template and instance using two of the custom content types and a default picture library that is programmatically customized when the feature is activated, e.g. it is assigned the third custom content type.

When deploying the solution and activating the feature, everything is set up correctly except a single taxonomy field for one of the doc lib's content types. It is defined to be required in both content types but indeed it does not show up as required for the default content type whereas everything works fine for the other. And it does not matter which of the two custom content types is defined first (= default) in the list template's schema.xml, the issue always occurs for the same taxonomy field in the doc lib's default content type. When I use the built-in Document content type as default, the field is required for both custom content types. However, using the Document content type is not an option.

If you think this behavior is not strange enough: When the list content type's field is set required through the SharePoint UI, it becomes optional again when the list column is updated, e.g. its display name is changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Erwin, were you able to figure out why this was happening. I am seeing a similar issue on something I am working on.

Comment: Hi Krishna, no, unfortunately I wasn't able to find the root cause. I finally worked around the issue by adding the Document content type in front of all custom content types in the list template and removing it later during the installation process by means of a PowerShell script.